# Modify Link with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working with some links and I am using CSS to control their appearence. I have done the normal look and the `a:hover` look, but I have problems with the `a:visited` look.

When I try to put the `a:visited` to change the color when visited, the `a:hover` stops working and it stops showing the change of colors.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a:visited` rule is probably *after* your `a:hover` rule, and since they have the same specificity, the last one overrides previous ones. Simply move `a:hover` to after `a:visited` and it should work. Alternatively, you could decrease the specificity of `a:visited` by changing it to `:visited`.

See [your probable problem](http://jsfiddle.net/rvUs9/), [one possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rvUs9/1/) by changing the order, and [the alternative solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rvUs9/2/) by changing the specificity.

You could also add `!important` to the `color` property ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/rvUs9/3/)) but that's not a good idea because it will override even later and more specific ones, plus old versions of Internet Explorer don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have other problem

look here

its working

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link